# Probability questions regarding an event E with appearing N times in K iterations

Tags: probability

Sorry, but I don't know how to properly Google this.

---

What's the probability of an event E with probability P happening **exactly** N times in K 'throws'?

What's the probability of an event E with probability P happening **atleast** N times in K 'throws'?

What's the probability of an event E with probability P happening **at most** N times in K 'throws'?

Comment: The search term you want is [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read about the Binomial Distribution. If the probability of the even happening in one trial is $p$ then the probability of the even happening exactly $N$ times in $K$ throws is

$$P(X=N)=\binom{K}{N}p^{N}(1-p)^{K-N}.$$

The probability of the event happening at least $N$ times in $K$ throws is

$$P(X>=N)=\sum_{i=N}^{K}\binom{K}{i}p^{i}(1-p)^{K-i}$$

and finally at most $N$ times is

$$P(X<=N)=\sum_{i=0}^{N}\binom{K}{i}p^{i}(1-p)^{K-i}$$

Comment: Oh, thank you, it's actually easier than I thought. As I understand it, the formula for 'atleast' can be interpreted as "The probability that it happens N times OR the probability that it happens N+1 times OR ... OR the probability that it happens K times" - correct?

Comment: at least N times means that the event can happen either N times or N+1 times or N+2 times and so on till $K$ times. That is why we sum the probabilities from N to K.

Comment: I see, that's clean. Yeah, I mean I actually came up with that myself, but I thought the Sigma was just some sort of workaround and there's a proper, cleaner way to compute this that doesn't include iteration - but apparently, this is the right method. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it follows a binomial law,
If it happens N times in K throws, $P(X=N) = C(K,N) \cdot P^N \cdot (1-P)^{K-N}$.
For $P(X>N) = \sum_{X>N} P(X)$ and $P(X<N) = \sum_{X<N} P(X)$.
Most of the time, in exercises, it's easy to calculate.